# my php mysql cant retrieve data from a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, hyperlink

My hyperlink which is supposed to retrieve data from one field in a mysql database is not working. it just shows /read.php?id= and to the rest of the id which is supposed to be generated dynamically. can anyone point out the mistake in my code

```
<a href="read.php?id="echo .{$row['fulltext']}.><input type="button" value="Read More" /></a>
```

Database connection and query

```
// connection string constants
    define('DSN', 'mysql:dbname=mytestdb;host=localhost');
    define('USER', 'myadmin');
    define('PASSWORD', '');

    // pdo instance creation
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, USER, PASSWORD);

    // query preparation
    $stmt = $pdo->query("
        SELECT fulltext
        FROM mydb_items
    ");

    // fetching results
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Well, show us your database connection and how you select data from it.  And that's just HTML trying to parse PHP, it doesn't work that way.

Comment: Show your db connections and query first.

Comment: You are mixing HTML & PHP. So what is the error?

Comment: I have added the connection and query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `<?php` after the 'id='.

Like this:

```
<a href="read.php?id=<?php echo $row['fulltext']; ?>"><input type="button" value="Read More" /></a>
```